# Proof by induction, basic level.

Tags: induction, propositional-calculus

i am supposed to prove by induction the next relation holds for every $n\geq1$ such that $n\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$\lnot(P_1\land\cdots\land P_n)=(\lnot P_1)\lor\cdots\lor(\lnot P_n)\tag{1}$$
Then my inductive hypotesis:
$$\lnot(P_1\land\cdots\land P_k)=(\lnot P_1)\lor\cdots\lor(\lnot P_k)\tag{2}$$
So, as (2) is true i tried by developing the following truth table, wish, i hope, is enough to prove the relation holds for any $k+1$.
\begin{array}{C|C|C|C|C|C}
P_1\land\cdots\land P_n & (\lnot P_1)\lor\cdots\lor(\lnot P_n) & P_{k+1} & (P_1\land\cdots\land P_n)\land P_{k+1} & ((\lnot P_1)\lor\cdots\lor(\lnot P_n))\land \lnot P_{k+1} & \lnot[(P_1\land\cdots\land P_n)\land P_{k+1}]\\
\hline
T & F & T & T & F & F\\
F & T & T & F & T & T\\
T & F & F & F & T & T\\
F & T & F & F & T & T
\end{array}
Since the two last columns share the same T/F values, the expressions are the same and i am proving (1) is true. I'm new to proving things so i'd really appreciate if you could tell me if am actually proving anything at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truth tables won't work here, because they would need to consider every possible value for P$_1$ up to P$_n$, which could make the truth table prohibitively large.

What you need to do is use the law:

($\lnot$(X$\land$Y)) = (($\lnot$X) $\lor$ ($\lnot$Y)).

You might start by writing:

$\lnot$(P$_1$ $\land$ ... $\land$ P$_n$ $\land$ P $_n$$_+$$_1$).

Then you associate to:

$\lnot$((P$_1$ $\land$ ... $\land$ P$_n$) $\land$ P $_n$$_+$$_1$).

Do you understand how to use the above law and what you can write on the other side of the '=' now?

Comment: I understand that if i keep associating and using the law, I'll eventually get to the expression $$(\lnot P_1)\lor\cdots\lor(\lnot P_k) \lor \lnot P_{k+1}$$. Im just not sure if that would be all the proof, i got to the desired relation but it feel like i am starting with what i'm supposed to prove. Is the proof over  by now?

Comment: @CoolJedi132 Actually, the above only covers the induction step.  You need to prove the base case which is where n = 2.  But, that also holds from the law.  There should exist some way to prove that law, or you should already have it as a given.  Then since you have a base case, and (P(n) $\rightarrow$ P(n+1)), the theorem follows.  I only covered the induction step, since I thought was the part you needed most.

Comment: Oh, okay i think i know now how to proceed.
Thank you very much; i hope i am using this site accordingly.